# Spring e EJB têm as mesmas funcionalidades?

Tags: java, spring, design-pattern, ejb

Spring e EJB têm as mesmas funcionalidades?

Se não, da para usar os dois em uma mesma aplicação?

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o CDI ao invés do Spring e serviços REST seguindo uma arquitetura de microserviços ao invés de EJBs. Para produtos mais novos, essas tecnologias se mostram bastante vantajosas.

Comment: Agradeço a dica, sou seguir. Atenciosamente

Answer (score 2):

Não, eles possuem propósitos diferentes. O Spring é uma framework que trabalha com injeção de dependências. O objetivo é facilitar a criação de objetos deixando isso a cargo de providers específicos e não das classes que utilizam as dependências. Já o EJB é utilizado para o desenvolvimento de projetos que utilizam uma arquitetura [SOA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture). Seu objeto é permitir a implementação de funcionalidades como serviços. Assim os sistemas tornam-se mais modulares e reusáveis, facilitando ainda a entrega contínua por serviço. Ambos podem ser utilizados na mesma aplicação, e inclusive são com muita frequência.

Comment: "No mercado atualmente é utilizado mais o CDI ". Qual a fonte desta informação? Tanto Spring quanto EJB (ou melhor, Java EE) são bem parecidos quando as funcionalidades que entregam: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29093892/2387977

Comment: http://blog.caelum.com.br/java-ee-versus-spring-retomando-a-discussao/. Uma referência, mas existem outras.

Comment: Me corrija se estiver enganado, mas no link que colocou mostra justamente o contrário: spring era mais utilizado. O artigo também é um pouco antigo, de 2012. Se for pegar um gráfico mais novo (para ser feito a justiça), usando "CDI", o mercado mostrava mais interesse que no Spring em 2012, mas já foi alcançado pelo Spring: http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends/q-java-and-ejb-q-java-and-spring-q-java-and-cdi-q-java-and-j2ee.html?relative=1, provavelmente pelo Spring 4 e suas inovações. Ainda assim, o número de vagas abertas não me parece confiável para saber qual é mais usado no mercado.

Comment: Essa é uma eterna discussão, foge do escopo do stackoverflow. O CDI é algo emergente, se você aplicar no mercado de produtos legados o spring e EJB estarão em alta. Mas pro futuro não vejo esse cenário durando muito.

Comment: Mudei a resposta para não dar margem a debates extensos.